# yii2 custom validation not working

Tags: validation, yii2, yii2-validation

I need to compare 2 attribute value in the model and only if first value is lower than second value form can validate.I try with below code but it not worked.

**controller**

```
public function actionOpanningBalance(){

     $model = new Bill();
     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->created_at = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $model->save();
      }else{
       return $this->render('OpanningBalance', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
     } 
}
```

**Model**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['outlet_id', 'sr_id', 'bill_number', 'bill_date', 'created_at', 'created_date','bill_amount','credit_amount'], 'required'],
        [['outlet_id', 'sr_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
        [['bill_date', 'd_slip_date', 'cheque_date', 'created_date', 'updated_date','status'], 'safe'],
        [['bill_amount', 'cash_amount', 'cheque_amount', 'credit_amount'], 'number'],
        [['comment'], 'string'],
        ['credit_amount',function compareValue($attribute,$param){
               if($this->$attribute > $this->bill_amount){
               $this->addError($attribute, 'Credit amount should less than Bill amount');
    }],           
        [['bill_number', 'd_slip_no', 'bank', 'branch'], 'string', 'max' => 225],
        [['cheque_number'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['bill_number'], 'unique']
    ];
}
}
```

It's going in to the validator function  but not add the error like i wanted

> $this->addError($attribute, 'Credit amount should less than Bill amount');

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: You should simply call `$model->validate()` ...

Comment: you mean add like if($model->validate()){"save model"} i did but not worked.

Comment: remove function name `comparevalue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function actionOpanningBalance(){

 $model = new Bill();
 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
    $model->created_at = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    $model->save();
  }else{
   return $this->render('OpanningBalance', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
 } 
}
```

**For Validation**

You can use anonymous function :

```
['credit_amount',function ($attribute, $params) {
            if ($this->$attribute > $this->bill_amount)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Credit amount should less than Bill amount.');
              return false;
            }
        }],
```

Comment: Try with anonymous function: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ad-hoc-validation

Comment: i found out that
$this->addError($attribute, 'Credit amount should less than Bill amount.');
not working

Comment: try adding: `'skipOnError' => false` in rules.

Comment: have you removed function name `compareValue`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96798/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-rumes-shyaman).

Answer (score 3):

If the validation is not adding any error, it's most likely being skipped.  The issue is most likely becasue of default rules behaviour whereby it skips empty or already error given values as per here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#inline-validators

Specifically:

> By default, inline validators will not be applied if their associated attributes receive empty inputs or if they have already failed some validation rules. If you want to make sure a rule is always applied, you may configure the skipOnEmpty and/or skipOnError properties to be false in the rule declarations.

So you would need to set up the `skipOnEmpty` or `skipOnError` values depending on what works for you:

```
[
    ['country', 'validateCountry', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this below answer is also write

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        ['credit_amount','custom_function_validation', 'on' =>'scenario'];
}
public function custom_function_validation($attribute){
    // add custom validation
    if ($this->$attribute < $this->cash_amount) 
        $this->addError($attribute,'Credit amount should less than Bill amount.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made custom_function_validation working using 3rd params like this:

```
public function is18yo($attribute, $params, $validator)
{
    $dobDate = new DateTime($this->$attribute);
    $now = new DateTime();
    if ($now->diff($dobDate)->y < 18) {
        $validator->addError($this, $attribute, 'At least 18 years old');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a back end validation and it will trigger on submit only. So you can try something like this inside your validation function.

```
if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
  // Your validation code goes here.
}
```

If you check the `basic Yii2` app generated you can see that example in file `models/LoginForm.php`, there is a function named `validatePassword`.

Validation will trigger only after submitting the form.